# Menu Driven Shell Script bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, menu

As a complete novice to this i am trying to make a Shell Script. This will be driven by a menu with options such as delete file. The part i am scuppered by is for example, when the menu is up, how to get from pressing '1', to actually creating a new file (as this is option 1 on my menu) I appreciate this may not be the easiest of questions to understand as my use of technical terms is limited, however i would appreciate any help. Below is an example of the first section of my menu. I feel once i know where to start i'll be fine
`Menu`

```
[1] Create File
[2] Delete File
[3] Rename file
```

Comment: I'm not very sure that `sh` or `bash` is the best tool for that (scripting languages are probably much more adequate). But you need to learn about the `read` builtin of `sh` and read http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ (which does have shortcomings).

Comment: It specifically has to be bash for the task ive been asked to complete. Thanks for your reply tho!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this for example :

```
select x in "Create File" "Delete File" "Rename file"; do
    echo "$x choosen"
    break
done
```

### Sample output

```
1) Create File
2) Delete File
3) Rename file
>
```

Search `select` in the *conditional construct* paragraph [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)

### Going further

To run some specific tasks with the result of the `$x` variable, you can use the `case` statement (like `switch` in other languages) like this :

```
case $x in
    Create*) touch file.txt ;;
    Delete*) rm -f file.txt ;;
    Rename*) mv file.txt file_old.txt ;;
esac
```

Comment: Added `case` to treat the result

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using switch/case statement. Please have a look on the bash manual or look for similar examples on the Web. Just google "switch case shell example"

Good luck