# Questions about shell script return method

Tags: bash, shell

I made a script to configure the server through the PXE.
When boot via pxe, The `shell.sh` appears on the server.
But if an incorrect value is entered in the script input paragraph(read), the power is turned off immediately.
Is there a way to return it to the input paragraph?

Added the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
(omit)
echo "*************************"
echo "Select script"
echo "      1) firmware"
echo "      2) capture"
echo "      3) get"
echo ""
echo "      4) SMBSET_FW+BIOSSET"
echo ""
echo "      b) bash shell"
echo "      n) systeminfo"
echo "      e) poweroff"
echo "      r) reboot"
echo "*************************${normal}"
read num

case $num in
    1) bash ./firmware.sh;;
    2) bash ./capture.sh;;
    3) bash ./get.sh;;
    4) bash ./smb.sh;;
    b) bash ./bash.sh;; 
    n) bash ./systeminfo.sh;; 
    e) poweroff -f;;
    r) reboot -f;;
esac
```

Comment: You need to use the select command: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Menu Driven Shell Script bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346161/menu-driven-shell-script-bash)

Comment: The code you posted does not behave as you describe. If you input e.g. `q` it will simply not execute any of the commands in the `case` statement. Voting to close as unreproducible.

Comment: Also, please use meaningful identifiers. Why num? You accept non-numbers as well. What about `choice`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code in a loop. Use `continue` to repeat the loop if they enter an unmatched response, otherwise break out of the loop.

```
while :; do
    echo "*************************"
    echo "Select script"
    echo "      1) firmware"
    echo "      2) capture"
    echo "      3) get"
    echo ""
    echo "      4) SMBSET_FW+BIOSSET"
    echo ""
    echo "      b) bash shell"
    echo "      n) systeminfo"
    echo "      e) poweroff"
    echo "      r) reboot"
    echo "*************************${normal}"
    read num
    
    case $num in
        1) bash ./firmware.sh;;
        2) bash ./capture.sh;;
        3) bash ./get.sh;;
        4) bash ./smb.sh;;
        b) bash ./bash.sh;; 
        n) bash ./systeminfo.sh;; 
        e) poweroff -f;;
        r) reboot -f;;
        *) echo "Invalid response, try again"; continue;;
    esac
    break
done
```